# Manage trust/add certificate

Tags: development, security, certificate

I try to add a certificate under `"central administration>security>manage trust"` but I always get the following error:

> The Root Certificate that was just selected is invalid. This may be
>   because the selected certificate requires a password and we do not
>   support certificates that require a password. Please select another
>   certificate.

It is a self created certificate.

More details [here](http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/configuring-certificates-and-trust-in-sharepoint-2010-for-accessing-exchange-web-services).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**I figured it out:** it does not work in `Mozilla Firefox` and `Google Chrome`. By using the internet-explorer (for entering the central administration and adding the certificate) everything work fine!

Comment: Perfect.. It has helped me as well...
Thank you for providing solution...

Answer (score 1):

One more piece to add to that answer... I was installing from the server's IE browser but was failing with this error. Did the exact same process from a client IE's browser and then it worked.